# MVVM subproperty change detection

Tags: mvvm, entity

My problem is as follows:

I am working with MVVM pattern and I would like to know how to detect changes of subproperties.

I have a textbox:

```
<TextBox Name="Descripcion" Text="{Binding AccionActual.Descripcion,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In the ViewModel I have the property:

```
Accion _accionActual;
public Accion AccionActual
    {
        get { return _accionActual; }
        set
        {
             _accionActual = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged("AccionActual");
        }
    }
```

The Accion entity definition is:

```
public partial class Accion : Entity
    {
        public Accion()
        {

            this.AccionesDocumentos = new HashSet<AccionDocumento>();

        }

        public int IdAccion { get; set; }
        public int IdEmpleado { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string DescripcionDetalle { get; set; }
        public bool Finalizada { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdExpediente { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdOrdenTrabajo { get; set; }
        public bool Facturable { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> GestComAlbaranAño { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> GestComAlbaranEmpresa { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> GestComAlbaranNumero { get; set; }
        public bool Facturado { get; set; }
        public bool ComputarHorasACliente { get; set; }
        public string DescripcionInterna { get; set; }

        public virtual Aplicacion Aplicacione { get; set; }
        public virtual AplicacionModulo AplicacionesModulo { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual ClienteContacto ClientesContacto { get; set; }
        public virtual Empleado Empleado { get; set; }
        public virtual Expediente Expediente { get; set; }
        public virtual OrdenTrabajo OrdenesTrabajo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AccionDocumento> AccionesDocumentos { get; set; }


    }
```

I could create in the ViewModel a property for each of the properties of Accion, but there any way to receive the changes without having to create a property for each of the properties of Accion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of redundant double wrapping by the ViewModel is a common problem in classic MVVM and drives me nuts too.

You have several options:

1. Have your entity implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and expose the Entity to the View the way you did it with the `AccionActual` property.
2. Hide your Entity completely behind a corresponding ViewModel object, and add only those properties to the ViewModel that you ***actually*** need in the View. Introduce a clever change notification infrastructure that notifies your ViewModel about changes in the Model and raise PropertyChanged in your ViewModel accordingly. This "change notifcation infrastructure" could be an [EventAggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) and maybe you can get away with some sort of bulk/meta update (e.g. raise NotifyPropertyChanged for all relevant properties in the ViewModel when you received the event "the entity changed".

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices- either modify the Accion class to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or create a ViewModel wrapper to do it.

Where you put this is up to you- do what works best for you. There is [a question on the merits of doing it in the ViewModel vs Model class here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772214/in-mvvm-should-the-viewmodel-or-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged).

You could take out the manual process of doing this by looking into something like [notifypropertyweaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver)- try using Google to look for INotifyPropertyChanged Aspect Oriented Programming. There is a Stackoverflow [question on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716400/simplest-way-to-achieve-automatic-notification-of-property-change).

Comment: either way @user1001552 will have to raise property changed event for each member and for that he/she has to implement a property for each member of the class Accion