# Call OnPropertyChanged from simple property

Tags: c#, data-binding, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I swear I have seen this but cannot seem to remember where.

I have simple properties (with no custom backing variable) as follows:

```
public string CityName { get; set; }
```

When the property changes I want the OnPropertyChanged event to fire.  I swear I have seen something like this

```
public long CityName {get; set { OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

but I cannot seem to find any examples.  Can you do what I am asking without having an independent backing variable?  The difference in my question is I do not want to use a variable to hold the value of the property.

Comment: May be this - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034840/handling-onpropertychanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034840/handling-onpropertychanged)

Comment: You can't put code in the setter of an auto-implemented property. I wish you could, but you can't. [Try snippets](https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/viewmodel-property-snippets-c6/). Won't save code, but it'll save typing and you can just collapse the `#region` and not have to look at it.

Comment: These example all appear to have backing variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to achieve automatic notification of property change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716400/simplest-way-to-achieve-automatic-notification-of-property-change)

Comment: No not a duplicate of the indicated question.  They all have backing variables also.  FYI in VB.Net you never need a backing variable for your property because one is automatically created for you by declaring the property. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears this can't be done in C#.